# Eigentlich vs Wirklich , What's the difference?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between eigentlich vs wirklich?
I know only dictionary meaning, at what time one is appropriate over other?

Comment: Google turns up several discussions about this. What did you learn there that you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following usage of *eigentlich* and *wirklich* makes the difference more clear:
1. "Kannst du mir helfen?" "Nein, ich habe wirklich keine Zeit. Ich muss zum Arzt."
2. "Kannst du mir helfen?" "Vielleicht, eigentlich habe ich keine Zeit, weil ich zum Arzt muss, aber ich könnte den Termin verschieben."